# How to make mobs not attack each other?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making a custom boss battle where it spawns mobs to fight for it, but the skeletons attack each other. How can I prevent this from happening in Minecraft 1.16.5?

I am using custom commands to summon the mobs, and I put them on the team `EndMobs` However, when I tried to spawn it with the tag `{Team:EndMobs}`, the command output says, "Unable to add mob to team. Are you sure the team exists?"

However, when i tried looking at the team, it said `[EndMobs]` so I decided to add the mob to `[EndMobs]` instead, and this time, console didn't throw out an error, so I assumed it worked. However, even if I modify the team with friendly fire off, they still attack each other. When one tries to shoot the player, they end up shooting another mob.

Comment: Hi, Shatterdest, welcome to the Arqade. Have you read [how to ask good questions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)? You could provide more information. How are you causing these mobs to spawn? Can you show us the code/setup?

Comment: I am using custom commands to summon the mobs, and I put them on the team "EndMobs" However, when I tried to spawn it with the tag {Team:EndMobs}, console said,"Unable to add mob to team. Are you sure the team exists" or something like that. However, when i tried looking at the team, it said [EndMobs] so i decided to add the mob to [EndMobs] instead, and this time, console didn't throw out an error, so I assumed it worked. However, even if I modify the team with FriendlyFire off, they still attack each other. When one tries to shoot the player, they end up shooting another mob and well, yeah.

Answer (score -1):

I have a theory, but it is only if you are currently in creative mode. Otherwise, I can not think of any other way to solve this. My theory is that you have to be in survival mode to make the skeletons fight you.

Comment: I spawned all the mobs together, and there's a lot of them, so if they try to attack me, they all end up shooting each other, and in turn aggro each other. I've tried adding them to a team and turning friendly fire for the tead off, but it still didn't work.